# jQuery : insert a tag in an input box, like Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I'm looking for a plugin to insert a selected tag in an input box, but all what I found are plugins to create automatically tags after typing them.

Output example :

[image]

If a user click a tag (eg : name1), the tag is inserted in an input box. It is particulary usefull to save time when you want to translate sthg for example.

Do you know if such plugin exist? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/). You have the ability to predefine the set of tags or allow users to enter new ones. You can block the choice of creating new ones by having an option `create: false`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery : click a tag and populate an input box with it</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="testbox" value="My Name is " />

<div>
    {<i id="Name1">Name1</i>}
    {<i id="Name2">Name2</i>}
    {<i id="Name3">Name3</i>}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("i").click(function(){
        var value = "My Name is";
        var al = $(this).text();
        var text = value + " " + al;
        $("#testbox").val(text);
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```